# Were the Knights of Ren always working for THIS character?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

During the course of the sequel trilogy viewers were introduced to a new group of characters called, The Knights of Ren.

[image: Kylo Comic Cover]

We came to understand (*The Force Awakens, The Rise of Kylo Ren Comic*) that after Ben Solo turned to the dark side and became Kylo Ren, he was inducted into the group and seemingly became their leader, as Snoke once refers to him as "The Master of Ren", and therefor it appears both were answering to Supreme Leader Snoke. Also *The Last Jedi* mentions they were on a mission, being absent from the film.

But the final film of the sequel trilogy, *The Rise of Skywalker*, very ambiguously gets into notions of Palpatine's and potentially, "The Sith's" return...

Early in the film Kylo Ren and the Knights of Ren seem to be working together, as Kylo finds the first Wayfinder (Sith Holocron) with their help and then later, they capture a well-known character that plays into what Kylo Ren was trying to do to get closer to Rey.

> But once Kylo Ren returns from the Dark Side and once again attempts to be Ben Solo, he goes back to Exogal presumably to help Rey face Darth Sidious. However, once he arrives on Exogal, he must face The Knights of Ren, before being able to enter the deeper chamber and throne room.

So does this mean that The Knights of Ren were always aligned with Darth Sidious?

Answer (score 4):

> So does this mean that The Knights of Ren were always aligned with Darth Sidious?

#### Yes, that's correct.

When Kylo Ren and Darth Sidious were speaking on Exogal, he explains how he had created Supreme Leader Snoke; **i.e., that Snoke was no more than an extension of Sidious himself** (presumably because of Sidious' physical limitations due to being in such poor health).

Once Kylo Ren abandoned the Dark Side and reverted back to being Ben Solo, the Knights of Ren appear to have rendezvoused to Exogal to guard Palpatine's chamber so that Ben Solo and/or anyone else wouldn't interfere with Darth Sidious' interaction with Rey.

Comment: While this might be a possible answer, its not definite. One reason I included TROKR comic in my Q is because there is a Snoke presented who has a VERY different personality to the one in the films. It's not clear if either Snoke(s) are clones of Sidious or if Snoke was cloned to help Siidous return, or if that is in fact truly Sidious or Sidious alone (Sith/Sith loyalists). The Mandalorian also leaves room that The Child could play a role in all of this too...

Comment: That's why I'm looking 4 a more solid answer, because a version of Sidious controlling a version of Snoke does not explain the semantics of their dynamic and ultimately where TKOR actually fit in.

Comment: I just provided an answer that's specific to the film that was tagged. I didn't read the comics and/or other non-film content. Maybe this question would be better received in scifi.se?

Comment: The comics/etc are canon and often fill in backstory, but it's also possible that the EPs could provide insight too, so I'm waiting to see, but the film left a lot of things open to questions IMO.

Comment: @DarthLocke I just mean that there are a lot more users on that site who read comics and would be more in-tune with non-film content. Though comic/non-film supported answers are acceptable on this site, they're fairly uncommon.